# Creating an SQL query that selects a specific entry in a table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table called grades that has 4 columns: **ID, math, science and history**.

I want to create an sql query that **selects from the table *"grades"* the specific entry where "ID" is equal to a variable**. This variable changes every time the program is run. What I have tried so far but is not working is this:

```
"SELECT * FROM grades Where ID LIKE %" + IDString + "%"

"SELECT * FROM grades Where ID LIKE %IDString%"

"SELECT * FROM grades Where ID LIKE 'IDString'"
```

*Note: IDString is the  String variable.*
*Note: I am using Java and Sqlite.*

```
String IDString = "12345";
ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM grades Where ID LIKE '%' || IDString || '%' ");
```

this code is to make my problem a little more clear.

Comment: In MySQL it would be `... WHERE ID LIKE "%something%"`
However never use string concatenation in SQL: Look up the term `SQL injection` and you will learn why

Comment: An example of a normalised schema might be student, subject, grade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat` function to concat the variable and strings.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable Where col2 LIKE CONCAT('%', @start, '%')
```

or in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM grades Where ID LIKE CONCAT('%', @IDString, '%')
```

[Here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=08d11291675364589a1705aa1007ec58)

In SQLite this would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM grades Where ID LIKE '%' || @IDString || '%'
```

But in SQLite you can not use variables. This needs to be done in your Java part of the code.

When sending the query from JAVA you can do it like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM grades Where ID LIKE '%' ||" + IDString + "|| '%' "
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208615/discussion-on-answer-by-vboka-creating-an-sql-query-that-selects-a-specific-entr).

Answer (score 1):

Your own examples are wrong because the pattern *literal* should be enclosed into single quotes. The pattern characters like % or _ will be inside the literal:

```sql
    SELECT * FROM grades Where ID LIKE '%IDString%'
```

If you'd like to *substitute a value* in the "pure MySQL", put the pattern characters into the variable, but not into query body:

```sql
    SET @pattern = CONCAT('%', @var, '%');

    SELECT * FROM grades WHERE ID LIKE @pattern;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vr13gVV19CTcR1kbgohS34/0

The same for PHP or other "external" languages. You can use prepared statement with a value which already contains pattern characters. Something like that:

```php
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM grades WHERE ID LIKE ?");
    $sth->execute('%' . $var . '%'));
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
```